# iOS SDK: How to cause view to flip when switching cameras

Tags: ios, animation, video, capture

Fairly new at iOS/Objective C.  I'm making mods to Apple's [AVCam](http://bit.ly/IFQn3h) (video capture) sample code and would like to imitate the native camera's flip animation when switching between front and back cameras.  It seems as if this would be easy but I can't get a handle on how it's done.  Advice would be welcome.

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 10):

It is indeed a simple task. All you need to do is call the method [`transitionWithView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:) from `UIView` right before changing the `previewView` input.

If you're targeting iOS 8.0 or later, you can also easily add a blur effect.

**Swift 2**

```
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: previewView.bounds)
blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
previewView.addSubview(blurView)

UIView.transitionWithView(previewView, duration: 0.4, options: .TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil) { (finished) -> Void in
    blurView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: previewView.bounds)
blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
previewView.addSubview(blurView)

UIView.transition(with: previewView, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil) { (finished) -> Void in
    blurView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
UIVisualEffectView *blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithFrame:_previewView.bounds];
blurView.effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
[_previewView addSubview:blurView];

[UIView transitionWithView:_previewView duration:0.4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [blurView removeFromSuperview];
}];
```